# SharePoint List Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to add 2 million items in a SharePoint list and around 1 million records have been added without any problem and after that I am getting out of memory exception.

I am using CAML Query to get 5000 records at a time and then I'm adding those records in list.

```
do {
   list<ListItemCollection> tx = new list<ListItemCollection>();
   ListItemCollection colListItem= oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
   tx.addrange(colListItem)
} while(colListItem.xxxposition != null)
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Why are you adding so many items in single list? have you considered adding items in folders inside list instead adding all items in list?

Comment: i'm adding all items in one list and then using that list ill create report..

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to add so many items directly into the list.

There are various ways to manage large lists and libraries in Sharepoint like:

1. Using indexed columns.
2. Using folders inside list to store the items.

You can read more about how to manage large lists or libraries using below links:

1. [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

Comment: does this answers your question?